# How to set property CharBitDataAsString in Db2 Database using .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, db2

I'm trying to fetch some data from Db2 Database using .NET Core 2.1

The problem is that i'm getting Byte[] instead of string as a result of my query :

```
using(var cmd = Connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = GET_OPERATIONS_QUERY;

    using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read())
            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));
    }
}
```

I have already encountered this problem but it was with

> IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries

The solution was to set the property CharBitDataAsString to true

```
iDB2ProviderSettings.CharBitDataAsString = true;
```

So how to do this with

- .Net Core 2.1
- IBM.Data.DB2.Core 1.3.0.100

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in your connection string, just add a `;CharBitDataAsString=true`
to the end of it.

Comment: No it doesn't work, i'm getting this error :

**ArgumentException: Invalid argument**

`IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2ConnPool.ReplaceConnectionStringParms(DB2Connection connection, string szValue, ref DB2ConnSettings pSettings, ref DB2ConnSettingsInternal pSettingsInternal, bool bAttach, bool pushDownStrAppended)`